# should we include or exclude a variable in a logistic regression based on the description below?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, variable-selection

should we include or exclude a variable in a logit regr. model which will only obtain values if a certain event takes place otherwise will show N/A?
this variable tells whether or not a product will be bought based on calls made by the company.
[the variable tells: number of days that passed by after the client was last contacted from a previous campaign. the values (-1) are for users who were not previously contacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNQP3.png)

Comment: You may want to make few bins of this data and study the impact. It is safe to assume that after a certain time period ( Say 2 months) the impact of contacting clients won't be significant. You can categorize this column data in few flags and try to estimate the impact if any.  Based on logistic regression results you can decide whether ignore this variable or not.

Comment: This type of questions, involving theory and not coding, should be asked in https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/